# How to store a data with foreign key after last insert on Java site?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, last-insert-id

I have 2 tables as *Tasks* and *Comments*, in Comments table there is a column as *TASKID* which is a foreign key for *ID* column of Tasks.

I am trying to store a task with CrudRepository, and TaskDto class has a comment property and I want to add it to Comments table as well.

Here is a sample code for storing Task

```
public TaskDto saveTask(TaskDto taskDto) {
        String comment = taskDto.getComment();
        try {
            taskRepository.save(modelMapper.map(taskDto, Task.class));
            // HERE I NEED A CODE FOR STORING comment TO OTHER TABLE BUT I NEED THE ID OF LAST STORED TASK ID TO STORE TASKID OF COMMENT
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // return bla bla
        }
        // return blabla;
    }
```

As you see in the code sample above, just after inserting Task, I need its primary key ID to store it to Comment table as well.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps set the task to the saved entity `comment.setTask(repo.save(...))`

Comment: thanks, i applied that solution